# HTML attributes without quotation marks?

Tags: html

I've always thought html requires quotation marks in his properties:

`<div class="service_definition">` or `<div class='service_definition'>`

But recently i noticed that the w3 validator doesn't recognize the following as an error:

`<div class=service_definition>`

So is it all right if i omit the quotation marks? Or are there any restrictions?

Comment: And take into account that if you use xhtml, you **must** use quotation marks always. See [xhtml differences with html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.4).

Comment: What version of html?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Always use quotation marks.**

I don't believe that HTML properties without quotation marks are classed as Invalid HTML, but they will potentially cause you problems later on down the line.

> By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using
>   either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation
>   marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within
>   the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks,
>   and vice versa. Authors may also use numeric character references to
>   represent double quotes (") and single quotes ('). For double
>   quotes authors can also use the character entity reference ".
>
> In certain cases, authors may specify the value of an attribute
>   without any quotation marks. The attribute value may only contain
>   letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), hyphens (ASCII decimal 45),
>   periods (ASCII decimal 46), underscores (ASCII decimal 95), and colons
>   (ASCII decimal 58). We recommend using quotation marks even when it is
>   possible to eliminate them.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

---

I think they're a great way of clearly defining when an attribute value starts and finishes.

Take for example the `class` attribute which can have multiple classes seperated by spaces:

```
<div class="classa classb" id="123">
```

This clearly shows the browser that my classes are `classa` and `classb`, with an element id of `123`.

Take away the quotation marks and we've got:

```
<div class=classa classb id=123>
```

A browser could now interpret this as 3 classes, with no id. `classa`, `classb` and `id=123`.

Or it may even interpret it as 3 attributes. `class="classa"`, `classb=""` and `id="123"`

(Even stackoverflow's syntax styling is struggling with this one!)

Comment: so this is a bug of the validator?

Comment: @Shylux No its not a bug, its just highly not recommended. See my edit.

Comment: the validator is not necessarily always correct, especially because HTML is a very "personal style" code, I wouldn't suggest adhering to its every rule. Just use whats standard and works in all browsers

Comment: `<div class=classa classb id=123>` - I believe the browser will interpret it as 3 attributes, `class="classa"`, `classb=""` and `id="123"`

Comment: SO's code coloring gets it perfectly right: `classb` is a *boolean attribute*, the other two are attributes with one value. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: @deceze Did you downvote on that basis, or is this a coincedence?

Comment: Just in general, your answer is not really correct. The behavior of quoted and unquoted attributes is perfectly well defined, there's no ambiguity. If you're dynamically creating HTML and may get into a situation like your `classb` example, then yes, quotes are a good idea. If you're hand-coding some HTML though, you *can* leave them out perfectly fine without problems.

Comment: "I see no reason, other than laziness, to leave out quotation marks." -> What about minification?

Comment: @Smaug Fair point - I've removed that statement from my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The rules depend on HTML version.

In all flavors of XHTML, attribute values must always appear in quotes, since XHTML is XML. Validators naturally check this. In browser practice, it's different. In genuine XML mode, a missing quote aborts document interpretation: the content is not shown, only an error message (which may contain an extract of source code) is shown to the user. But when XHTML is served as HTML, which is the normal way (especially due to the XHTML-illiteracy of old versions of IE) browsers treat it by HTML rules.

Otherwise in HTML, the formal rules vary by specification, but browsers accept attribute values without quotation marks. HTML5 drafts reflect this liberal attitude: the quotes are needed only if the value contains a space, a line break, grave (`), equals sign (=), less than sign (<), greater than sign (>), Ascii quote ("), or Ascii apostrophe (').

What you do in practice is large a matter of convention, and it should depend on the opinions of coworkers or others who may work on your code, rather than public opinion. Many people think that the restrictive syntax of XHTML is cool. Others may think that unnecessary quotes mess up the code and have even some risks: whenever you need to use some characters in pairs, there’s always a chance of forgetting the closing component or mistyping it.

Answer (score 6):

**You can omit the quotes from an attribute value if the value consists of the following characters only (cf to the technical concept of name):**

```
letters of the English alphabet (A to Z, a to z)
digits (0 to 9)
periods .
hyphens -
```

Thus, WIDTH=80 and ALIGN=CENTER are legal shorthands for WIDTH="80" and ALIGN="CENTER". A reference to a URL like HREF=foo.html is acceptable, but in general URLs must be quoted when used in attributes, e.g. HREF="http://www.hut.fi/". - Some browsers are more permissive. Some browsers may even accept elements with a starting quote but without any closing quote. Such use is very bad practise.

refer http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML3.2/3.4.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can use HTML properties without quotation marks.

I recently created a text document in SharePoint that links to a company web application. I was getting an error message when using quotation marks for an href value (website url). Which is technically correct.

I noticed in the DOM, that a set of quotes was being added automatically to the href value by the browser. So I tried entering the href value without quotation marks, this fixed the navigation error.

Answer (score 0):

The w3 validator shows it as an error for me:

```
An attribute value specification must be an attribute value literal unless SHORTTAG YES is specified.
```