# Input NAME Tag With Quotation Marks?

Tags: html, forms

For an `<input>` html element - can quotation marks be omitted around the name, like this?

```
<input type="text" id="nameText" name=nameTextBox>
```

Or do I have to include the quotation marks, like this?

```
<input type="text" id="nameText" name="nameTextBox">
```

I am keeping in mind that when the form is processed the name value is sent along with the entered value.

Comment: cfr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837063/html-properties-without-quotation-marks

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes

Comment: There is nothing special about the `name` attribute in this respect, so this is a duplicate of a question about quoting attribute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotation marks are optional, but I would consider them "good practice"

EDIT: And, as deceze pointed out, conditions are met, such as no spaces, single or double quotes, or equal signs in your name (or other attribute).  I just use them, makes code easier to read, IMO.

Comment: Optional *iff* certain conditions are met...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am attempting to debug a script, and trying to figure out the processing errors - so I wanted to double check.

Comment: What would happen if no `<input type=...?` was declared?  If it just contains the `id` and `name`?

Comment: @Dustin It defaults to `text`.

Comment: it defaults to a text input

Comment: It will also default to "text" if it comes across one that it doesn't understand, like `type="tel"` on IE8 or `type="hibbityjibbity"` on any browser.