# Html attributes: quoted or unquoted?

Tags: html

For some html attributes, I can use quotes around the values, or not:

For example, I can do

```
<table colspan='1'></table>
```

Or

```
<table colspan=1></table>
```

Is there any difference between these two ways? Which is the more conventional way of doing things?

Comment: To play nice with your fellow programmers and reduce errors, always use some form of quotes to delineate the values you are setting for your attributes.

Comment: And although this is a good question, it may be considered to be off-topic because it can lead to a subjective discussion, which is not something that SO is focused on.  Cheers.

Comment: Related: [Do you quote HTML5 attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6495310)

Comment: Related: [HTML properties without quotation marks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837063/html-properties-without-quotation-marks)

Comment: Thank you, the above links are very informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your values in quotes (single or double, just don't mix them):

1. It's necessary for many values ( `class="container modal warning"` )
2. It prevents confusing values with later attributes ( `class="foo"id="bar"` )
3. People will like you, and treat you kindly.

During [Tokenization](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization), all three are considered ([single](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28single-quoted%29-state), [double](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28double-quoted%29-state), and [none](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-value-%28unquoted%29-state)).