# CSS : Float a number value on the right top corner of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float a number on the right top of an image.
I want this number to have a background-color and overlay on top of a small portion of the image on the right top corner.

[image]

I have tried :

```
<li class=topoulimg><span id=bell><img src=img-img/bell.png alt=alerts></span><span class=bellnumbers>10</span></li>
```

css

```
.bellnumbers{
float:right;
font-size:12px;
background-color:red;
width:10px;
height:10px;
color:#fff;
}
```

but it is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/yv5q4gvm/

Comment: [HTML properties without quotation marks?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9837063/5297207) it's hurting my eyes! See the class example in the top answer for an example how this could be problematic. Alt could potentially have this problem too... (I hope this was just laziness for the sake of the example, but if not, I recommend breaking this habit).

Comment: it is easier in php when you have an echo ""; for example, you dont need to scape quotes. I leaned that quotes is no longer needed, so I usually don't use them! haha but thank you a lot, I will starting using quotes again in my projects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
<span class="bell">
        <img src=https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicio/64x64/message.png alt=alerts>
    <span class="bellnumbers">10</span>
</span>

.bell {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 48px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.bell img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.bellnumbers {
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:red;
    width:16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/yv5q4gvm/27/)

Comment: this solve my problem! I don't know why but in my real project the position absolute is not working for this, the number goes to the other side of the screen... but your solution works nice! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `position:absolute` instead `float:right` for your badge (Adjust your needs).

**CSS**

```
.bell {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:64px;
}

.bellnumbers {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:red;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    color:#fff;
    top: -4px;
    right: -4px;
}
```

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5q4gvm/7/)**

Comment: strange that in my localhost the inside number is always outside of the red square (in the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Insert content from html attribute (`data-count`).

```
<button data-count="16"></button>
```

Insert content before every `<button>` element's content, and style the inserted content:

```
button:before {
    content: attr(data-count);
}
```

See the live example below:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicio/64x64/message.png");
  background-color: white
}

button:before {
  content: attr(data-count);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #FF9727;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}

button.bell-top-right:before {
  left: auto;
  right: -10px;
}

button.bell-bottom-right:before {
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}

button.bell-bottom-left:before {
  top: auto;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<button data-count="16" class="bell-top-right"></button>
<button data-count="16" class="bell-bottom-right"></button>
<button data-count="16"></button>
<button data-count="16" class="bell-bottom-left"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. perhaps it will solve your purpose (try bootstrap badges that can be a help to)

```
<li>
    <span class=bell>
       <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicio/64x64/message.png">
            <span class=bellnumbers>10</span>
     </span>
 </li>


<style>
.bellnumbers{
vertical-align: top;
font-size:17px;
letter-spacing: 3px;    
background-color:#F06861;
width:27px;
height:22px;
color:#fff;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-top: 3px;    
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -1%;
margin-top: -5px;    
}
.bell{
    width:64px;
    margin-top: 5%;

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have shown, absolute/relative positioning and 'inline-block' on the li are ideal for this. I've got the code trimmed down quite a bit, however. Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/r09d314v/

```
<style type="text/css">

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
  }

  span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: -10px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
  }

</style>


<li>
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicio/64x64/message.png">
  <span class="number">11</span>
</li>
```