# Align number over image to top right corner or on the top of image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image in a navigation item and a number that I want to appear that gets updated on page loading, this number should either "sit" on top of the image or to the north east corner(top right).   I cannot get it to align correctly.  The best i have achieved is a social distanced to the right.

I have looked at both the examples here:
[CSS : Float a number value on the right top corner of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767050/css-float-a-number-value-on-the-right-top-corner-of-an-image)
[How to put the number at top right corner of cart icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304169/how-to-put-the-number-at-top-right-corner-of-cart-icon)

Here is what I have from the second link above:
[image: Item Icon]

I have currently got this piece of html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
     <a href="Cart1.aspx" class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 25px">
     <label ID="lblCartCount" ForeColor="White"/><img alt="basket" height="30" src="images/basket.png" />3</a>
</li>
```

styles:

```
    <style>

.header{background:rgb(0, 178, 255);color:#fff;}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.bell {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:64px;
}

.bellnumbers {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:red;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    color:#fff;
    top: -4px;
    right: -4px;
}
.badge {
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.label-warning[href],
.badge-warning[href] {
  background-color: #c67605;
}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: -10px; 
}
</style>


I like that the colour of the number is transparent actually, in the first example above its a background colour.

I have also tried this previously:
<li class="nav-item">
                            
                            <div class="cart update">       
                                <a class="nav-link" id="cart-link" th:href="@{/cart}" ><img alt="basket" height="30" src="images/basket.png" />
                                <span class="badge badge-warning" id="lblCartCount"><i class="fa" style="font-size:12px">[[${cartItemsSize}]]</i></span></a>
                            </div>
                    
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `<img>` and the `<span>` into a `div`. Then give the div the property and values of: `position: relative;` and `width: min-content;`. The first is needed to give a child element with `position: absolute;` an anchor/border. The `width: min-content;` is needed so that the div only uses up as much space as the image takes and not spanning the entire website width.

Last but not least, give the span element the properties and values of: `position: absolute; top: x; right: y;` give the as top and right a value of the distance to the image border you like.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

.image-wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg">
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but I just get the same thing, the number 5 is appearing to the right of the image.  I am wondering if there is something wrong with the image alignment as I have to reduce the size height to 30 to fit in the nav bar:       `<li class="nav-item">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
         <img src="images/basket.png" height="30">
         <span>5</span>
        </div>
       </li>  `   Actually it doesnt matter what size the image is the number is always to the right.

Comment: have you added the css lines aswell?

Comment: Yes i misplaced it in with another style, it looks better but too far to the right but ill sort that. good stuff

Comment: then simply raise the value of `right: 5px;` the higher the value the more to the left the span will move.