# Why are CSS attribute values denoted using strings in the tag itself but not in the rule?

Tags: html, css

I'm taking a HTML/CSS class and my professor doesn't use strings in the style sheet but does when its an attribute within a tag. For instance:

```
#name{
     color: blue
}
<div id = "name"> ... </div>
```

Will removing the quotation marks change something? Why does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put classes IDs in quotes, they may work, but can cause trouble down the line. There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837063/html-attributes-without-quotation-marks) here on SO that goes into more detail. Your code may also get flagged when using code validators.

Whatever you end up using, it may be good to maintain consistency, especially when working collaboratively—and agree upon a standard method on your team.

As an example of it working with and without, I modified your code to demonstrate.

```css
#name {
  color: blue;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background: yellow;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="name" class=box> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One is HTML language while the other is CSS language they have completely different syntax as they are for very different purpose.

When you write <div style="color:blue"> That is HTML and only the string argument of style will be parsed as CSS language, but to the HTML it's just a string with no special meaning.

You can combine CSS and HTML in the same file by putting the CSS inside <STYLE> tags which are themselves part of HTML not CSS...
It may seem confusing at first that we have different languages (HTML/CSS/Javascript/PhP...) but eventually they are for different purposes and having them very different syntax, I find, helps me identify the disparate concepts I'm working with.

p.s. removing the " is a bad idea. It's an anachronism... keep them clearly as strings for the HTML parser so that if you do need to put white space in a parameter the system won't freak out. One thing I would like is for them all to handle the same style comments, but it's not that important.