# I have a program that reads data and makes it into a table. But the header won't stick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a program that reads the variable "data" and puts all the values on a table. Everything is working great except for the header. I call .table-sticky when I define myTable in the  tag, but the header won't stick. Does anybody know why?

```css
.table-sticky-container {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 410px;
  margin-left: 803px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.table-sticky th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    
<div class="table-sticky-container">
  <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var data = ["NuggetCraft", "8:30", "8:45", "ChickenCraft", "9:30", "9:45", "MoneyCraft", "10:30", "10:45", "SpaceCraft", "11:30", "11:45", "NachumCraft", "12:30", "12:45", "SpecialCraft", "13:30", "13:45","BinkleCraft", "14:30", "14:45", "SchnitzelCraft", "15:30", "15:45", "CoolCraft", "16:30", "16:45", "PianoCraft", "17:30", "17:45", "QuadCraft", "18:30", "18:45", "CalfCraft", "19:30", "19:45"];

      var myTable = "<table class=table table-sticky><thead class=thead-light><tr><th>Name</th><th>Time in</th><th>Time out</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";

      var perRow = 3;
      data.forEach((value, i) => {
        myTable += `<td>${value}</td>`;

        var next = i + 1;
        if (next % perRow == 0 && next != data.length) {
          myTable += "</tr><tr>";
        }
      });

      myTable += "</tr></tbody></table>";

      document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = myTable;
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of how you are assigning attribute values inside the script tags **i.e, without quotation marks**

```
var myTable = "<table class=table table-sticky><thead class=thead-light><tr><th>Name</th><th>Time in</th><th>Time out</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
```

Here the table class has two value table and table-sticky but since you have not used any quotation marks, the browser interprets those values very differently as explained here
[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837063/html-attributes-without-quotation-marks). The second class is interpreted as another attribute instead of a value.

Do it like this,

```
var myTable = '<table class="table table-sticky"><thead class="thead-light"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Time in</th><th>Time out</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr>';
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!